# Faster methods to create geodataframe from a Dask or Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, gis, geospatial, geopandas

**Problem**

I'm trying to clip a very large block model (5.8gb CSV file) containing centroid x, y, and z coordinates with an elevation raster. I'm trying to obtain only the blocks lying just above the raster layer.

I usually do this in ArcGIS by clipping my block model points to the outline of my raster and then extracting the raster values to the block model points. For large datasets this takes an ungodly amount of time (yes, that's a technical term) in ArcGIS.

**How I want to solve it**

I want to speed this up by importing the CSV to Python. Using Dask, this is quick and easy:

```
import dask
from dask import dataframe as dd

BM = dd.read_csv(BM_path, skiprows=2,names=["X","Y","Z","Lith"])
```

But creating a GeoDataFrame using geopandas is not a fast process whatsoever. I thought that speeding it up using the following multiprocessing code might work:

```
import multiprocessing as mp
from multiprocessing import pool
import geopandas as gpd

pool=mp.Pool(mp.cpu_count())
geometry = pool.apply(gpd.points_from_xy, args=(BM.X,BM.Y,BM.Z))
pool.close()
```

However, I am an hour into waiting for this to process with no end in sight.

I have also tried putting the entire geodataframe together all at once in the following code but realize there are some syntax errors that I don't know how to correct, particularly with passing "geometry=" to args=:

```
pool = mp.Pool(mp.cpu_count())
results = pool.apply(gpd.GeoDataFrame, args=(BM,geometry=(BM.X,BM.Y,BM.Z)))
pool.close()
```

I was wondering if anyone had a better idea as to how I could speed this up and make this process more efficient, whether or not I am able to parallelize.

Comment: Have you tried using geopandas? Is it slow with geopandas too?

Comment: Hey there, thanks for the response. Yes! I tried geopandas (forgot to show the import but that was imported as "gpd") and I would like to find a way to parallelize geopandas to make it faster for massive datasets.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The optimal way of linking dask and geopandas is the dask-geopandas package.

```py
import dask
from dask import dataframe as dd
import dask_geopandas

BM = dd.read_csv(BM_path, skiprows=2,names=["X","Y","Z","Lith"])
BM["geometry"] = dask_geopandas.points_from_xy(BM,"X","Y","Z")
gdf = dask_geopandas.from_dask_dataframe(BM, geometry="geometry")
```

This gives you partitioned `dask_geopandas.GeoDataFrame`. If you want to convert it to a standard `geopandas.GeoDataFrame`, you just call `compute()`.

```py
gpd_gdf = gdf.compute()
```

Comment: Initially dask_geopandas wasn't working for me, but with some finagling I was able to install the package with conda-forge and then I had to uninstall rtree's prior version 0.9.7 to reinstall 0.9.3 or download pygeos instead to get this running. Thanks for your help!

Comment: dask-geopandas requires pygeos, rtree is not used in it.

Comment: Thanks! Yes, but for some reason I couldn't Conda search dask-geopandas, I had to conda -c conda-forge dask-geopandas and when I did so I was getting rtree installation errors. Turns out, based on a separate thread, it's a common issue. So I installed pygeos and I guess there's a routine in geopandas that uses pygeos instead when installed. Just some package funkiness I was having.